# understanding "this" keyword in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, splash-screen

I'm having a confusion regarding "this" keyword. Here are two code samples which are giving same output so what is the difference between them? And I do have other screen classes too. But game's starting point is SplashScreen.

```
public class GDXGame extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create() {
        AssetLoader.load();
        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        AssetLoader.dispose();
    }
}
```

And 2nd:

```
public class GDXGame extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create() {
        AssetLoader.load();
        setScreen(new SplashScreen());
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        AssetLoader.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current instance of the current class, so the 1st example sends the current `GDXGame` class instance from which `#create()` is being called to the `SplashScreen` constructor, whereas the second is calling the empty constructor for `SplashScreen`.  As to why they behave the same, or appear to, that depends on what an instance of `SplashScreen` does with the reference to the`GDXGame`